# Simple Generator-monitor program with condition variables

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, condition-variable

I created a simple program that uses condition variables to create synchronization between two threads.  I'm getting a strange output that I cannot seem to find the solution to.

**What the program does is**, in the generator thread, produces 1000 random integers and checks to see if they are perfect squares.  If the number is a perfect square then it signals the monitor thread which prints the square root of the number.

**The problem** I am having is most likely some sort of race condition, because the monitor simply isn't printing out the square root when the generator signals.

**The strange part** is that when I debug in gdb b stepping through each time the variable `is_square` changes, the problem is nonexistent.

Any insight would appreciated.  I feel it has to do with my mutex or placement of conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int square_root;
int is_square = 0;
int done = 0;
int count = 0; //used to count how many perfect squares generator_func finds
int count1 = 0; //used to compare how many responses monitor makes to signal
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t mon;


void* generator_func(void* args){
  srand(time(NULL)); 
  int i, temp, sq;
  for(i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    temp = rand() % 10000;
    sq = sqrt((double)temp);
    if((pow(sq,2)) == temp){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      count++;
      square_root = sq;
      is_square = 1;
      fprintf(stderr, "Square root of %d is", temp);
      pthread_cond_signal(&mon);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    } 
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  done = 1;
  is_square = -1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&mon);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


main(){
  pthread_t generator; //declare thread

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //initialize mutex
  pthread_cond_init(&mon, NULL); //initialize condition variable


  pthread_create(&generator, NULL, generator_func, NULL); //create thread

  //monitor
  while(done != 1){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(is_square == 0){
      pthread_cond_wait(&mon, &mutex);
    }
    if(is_square == 1 && done != 1){
      count1++;
      fprintf(stderr, " %d\n", square_root);
      is_square = 0;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  }

  pthread_join(generator, NULL);

  printf("%d %d\n", count, count1); //shows inconsistency between generator and monitor
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&mon);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All,
I have solved this problem very, very easily.  I am embarrassed for not catching this sooner, but I took a break from this code for a while.  The solution is so trivial.  All that was needed was an extra condition variable that the generator waits on until the monitor is finished.  Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int square_root;
volatile int is_square = 0;
int done = 0;
int count = 0; //used to count how many perfect squares generator_func finds
int count1 = 0; //used to compare how many responses monitor makes to signal
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t mon, gen;


void* generator_func(void* args){
  srand(time(NULL)); 
  int i, temp, sq;
  for(i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    temp = rand() % 10000;
    sq = sqrt((double)temp);
    if((pow(sq,2)) == temp){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      count++;
      square_root = sq;
      is_square = 1;
      fprintf(stderr, "Square root of %d is", temp);
      pthread_cond_signal(&mon); //signal monitor
      pthread_cond_wait(&gen, &mutex); //wait for monitor to finish *Solution*
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    } 
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  done = 1;
  is_square = -1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&mon);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


main(){
  pthread_t generator; //declare thread

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //initialize mutex
  pthread_cond_init(&mon, NULL); //initialize condition var for monitor
  pthread_cond_init(&gen, NULL); //initialize condition var for generator

  pthread_create(&generator, NULL, generator_func, NULL); //create thread

  //monitor
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while(done != 1 || is_square == 1){
    while(is_square == 0){
      pthread_cond_wait(&mon, &mutex);
    }
    if(is_square == 1 && done != 1){
      count1++;
      fprintf(stderr, " %d\n", square_root);
      is_square = 0;
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&gen); //start generator back up *Solution*
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


  pthread_join(generator, NULL);

  printf("%d %d\n", count, count1); //shows inconsistency between generator and monitor
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&mon);
}
```

Comment: Be aware that your solution will force a context switch after *every* found root. Your program is now correct, but will be very slow.

Comment: @thiton of course.  I would hope correctness supersedes performance though!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with conditional variables. There is one big pitfall here and it's probably happening to you: **If you call signal on a conditional variable but no thread is waiting on it, the signal is lost**.

My guess is that your main thread does not manage to reach the call to wait by the time the generator thread calls signal (it may call it several times by the time the main thread reaches wait), and that is why you are losing some values.

The debugger is not a good way of examining this, because it tends to make these subtle timing bugs go away.

Other problems:

1. The generator might finish before the main thread even reaches the while.
2. done should be volatile because it's modified cross-thread.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  I had intended to declare the generator after the monitor starts to wait, but I did not know how to go about doing this.

Comment: Your best option in this case is probably to implement a producer-consumer queue. Search it online and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Sorry for retracting your answer as correct, but I have solved the problem.  See my answer for VERY simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect all shared (global) variables by the mutexes. Firstly, this means moving the mutex calls in `main`:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while(done != 1){
   while(is_square == 0){
...
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

Secondly, you should be aware that you'll only see a handful of square roots, not all that the generator found. If the generator is fast enough, you'll even see no square roots, because the subthread can finish running before `main` sees the `while (done != 1)` loop.

You might consider using a buffer to store the found square roots.

Comment: I actually had the mutex that way originally, it doesn't seem to make a difference with the output.  I will put it back that way though.  That explanation makes sense to why the outputs aren't being displayed.  Do you think the buffer will solve the problem?

Comment: @TrevorArjeski: Yes. Actually, even checking in the outer while loop of `main` for `done != 1 || is_square == 1` should ensure that at least *one* square is found. However, the output will still be pretty garbled, with a sequence of line starts and only one ending.

Comment: Actually,, if the main thread is not able to even reach the while by the time the generator finishes all the numbers, the program will deadlock because the main thread will reach the wait and just block.

Answer (score 0):

this code should do the trick:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

int square_root;
int is_square = 0;
int done = 0;
int count = 0; //used to count how many perfect squares generator_func finds
int count1 = 0; //used to compare how many responses monitor makes to signal
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t mon;


void* generator_func(void* args){

    //sleep(1);
    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++);  // Some delay to hit a time-slice

  srand(time(NULL)); 
  int i, temp, sq;
  for(i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    temp = rand() % 10000;
    sq = sqrt((double)temp);
    if((pow(sq,2)) == temp){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      count++;
      square_root = sq;
      is_square = 1;
      fprintf(stderr, "Square root of %d is", temp);
      pthread_cond_signal(&mon);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    } 
  }
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  done = 1;
  is_square = -1;
  pthread_cond_signal(&mon);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}


int main(){
  pthread_t generator; //declare thread

  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL); //initialize mutex
  pthread_cond_init(&mon, NULL); //initialize condition variable


  pthread_create(&generator, NULL, generator_func, NULL); //create thread

  //monitor
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);  // Protect your variables here
  while(done != 1){
    while(is_square == 0){
      pthread_cond_wait(&mon, &mutex);
    }
    if(is_square == 1 && done != 1){
      count1++;
      fprintf(stderr, " %d\n", square_root);
      is_square = 0;
    }
  }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  pthread_join(generator, NULL);

  printf("%d %d\n", count, count1); //shows inconsistency between generator and monitor
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
  pthread_cond_destroy(&mon);

return 0;
}
```

You can you a loop to delay that is long enough to hit a time slice before so that your main can rush to wait on the cond_signal(). In the alternative, is to have another mechanism to allow your generator_func() thread to wait on for the main thread to signal it.

Then again, there is a sleep() feature you can use if your library has support for it.

Hope it helped!

Cheers,
Vern

Comment: Sadly, the sleep didn't help.  I think I will try to write a new program where the main() signals the generator.  Thanks

Comment: Even with a long sleep count it didn't work? That's interesting ... I'm just curious as to what is your OS' tick resolution :) Yes, to signal from main is the best way forward :) Cheers!